# Could not find or load main class test

Tags: java, command-line

I have already come across this error. I couldn't figure out today also.

```
   package com.example.cassandra;

   public class test
   {
     public static void main(String[] a)
     { 
        System.out.println("test");
     }
   }
```

This is my java file. My working directory is

```
  com/example/cassandra
```

Compile command is

```
  javac test.java
```

Changed working directory to parent directory of com

```
  cd ../../..
```

Run command

```
  java test
```

Says

```
  could not find or load main class test
```

Any body please explain what's the problem here?

Comment: Not conflicting, look carefully at the command lines they run along with their current directories and package names, and on your machine, `cd` to the parent of `com` and try running this command.

Comment: you have missed static keyword in main() functions definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to actually specify the package name:

```
java com.example.cassandra.test
```

Comment: @GopsAB Not conflicting, look carefully at the command lines they run along with their current directories and package names, and on your machine, `cd` to the parent of `com` and try running this command. They're running it inside the package folder, which is wrong.

Comment: @GopsAB Just try it and see.

Comment: @GopsAB: No conflict at all - in the answer there, the OP was advised to run `java test.test` which is again the fully-qualified classname.

Comment: @hexafraction thanks. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/cassandra/test (wrong name: org/example/cassandra/test)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)` I tried the suggested one here and i got this error. But test.class is present in the specified directory